# how to change spacific div opacity in iframe where is multiple div's

Tags: jquery

For Testing first, being as developer, I tried to submit few addresses on MapQuest for route planner and it show me on a new tab with Map and driving directions successfully, however if i do same within iframe it submit all addresses and when i click "Get Directions" the map with listing of addresses on left side is appearing but it do not show Travel Option and Driving Direction. Is there any restriction or reason that I can't see the same feature when i use mapquest route planner page within iFrame?

i check this issue when i submit mapquest request to iframe mapquest change Div Opacity so thats way its not showing in iframe i try to change opacity by jquery after submit in iframe but its not get div css value

screen short attached when i set opacity 1 its work by default opacity 0 when open in iframe without iframe its opacity 1![enter image description here][1]

```
function onLoad() {
    //$('#ifram').select('div', true).setOpacity(0.5);
    $('#ifram').find('#div').html();
}
```

Comment: Was my answere helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ifram').find('div.divClassName').css({ opacity: 0.5 });
```